# File tracking and deletion-needing-approval, on Windows 7 (SP1 64-bit) systems?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server

Trying to get a Win7 media library/fileserver set up , and I'd like to set up some sort of auditing to track file moves/additions/etc. There'd be no 'editing' of files, simply additions/deletions/moves/renames/etc. AND if possible some sort of system to queue any such changes to the file system pending approval by an authorized admin.

I.e.: Joe has access rights and renames the files in STUFF/FOLDER1, then moves FOLDER1 from STUFF/FOLDER1 to THINGS/FOLDER1, but the changes aren't published to the filesystem until an admin say 'do it', or decides 'discard [one or both actions]'.

I hope that's reasonably clear? File auditing by itself, to see who does what, would be doable with the built in policies, as I understand, but what about allowing conditional modification, pending an (approved) administrative user's approval of the actions?

What are the options here? Anything open source/freeware/etc that would be available to do that? (Preferably integrated 'behind the scenes' into windows' disk explorer)

**EDIT:**  Haven't been able to find an answer to this yet, short of packages costing $$$$...  Surely there's something out there that can provide tracking and at least basic approval-required deletion? I want to set this up so I can delegate out the indexing/sorting to other people, but keep things from being accidentially deleted, yet allow rename/moving, and I don't see any way to do it nativly under NTFS permissions.

Comment: There's nothing open source/freeware, at all?  I'm even willing to consider a GUI linux solution even (debian/ubuntu preferred), if I can get the MegaRaid/LSI drivers and windows share running under it easilly.

I'd prefer a windows solution, though, and would even offer a bounty if I had the rep for it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about such a product, too. But I can give you idea for a workaround:

What can be done is to

1. deny all permissions except `read` to files in the library
2. set up a [request tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_Tracker) (ticketing tool, there are many: [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_help_desk_issue_tracking_software), [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems); I'm using self-hosted open source [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org/)) where users have to fill a request (ticket) for deletion or renaming. After admin's approval, the action can be done *automatically*. I mean, if request form is filled correctly, there is not a big problem to issue necessary move/delete command based on its data. If you make entering requests simple enough by removing unnecessary default form fields (severity, priority, subject, etc.), then this might be very easy to use because the entire form could have only two fields:

   ```
   Full Path of File:   [...............................]
   New File Name*:      [...............................]
      *enter new file name with or without path OR enter 'd' to delete the file
                        [Submit]  [Cancel]
   ```

   **Tip:** Users can be taught one simple trick to **copy full path** of desired file into the form:
   If the file is clicked with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Right Click*, its context menu reveals ***Copy as path*** command. Then user can instantly paste full path of the file into request form – no typing needed.

This approach is consistent with approach in large enterprises where tickets are used for IT needs. Later you can extend the tracker also for other types of requests so this can be a basis for more universal user care solution in the future.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you! I'm not sure it'll do what I'm looking for, but it's a promising direction, thanks!  I'll set up MantisBT in a VM and gnaw at it, and see what else is available, too.

Comment: @Christiebunny - this solution will do what you are looking for only after you *customize it*, e.g. simplify the form, create move/delete automation, etc. Adoption can take 20-100 hours. If there is a programmer around, maybe easier (although less universal considering future purposes) could be writing simple form by yourself.  
Anyway, if there is not ready-made solution around, I have shown you a way to go although it is not a short one. On the other hand, it is not different from what large companies do: they purchase a tracker and then let paid consultants to customize it for their needs.

Comment: I'll keep looking around, I'm still hoping for something more ready-made and integrated,  but if I can't find something in about a week, I'll give this a try.  I appreciate the help very much!  I'd originally considered trying to write something myself, but quickly realized it's light-years beyond what little programming skills I have!

Comment: @Christiebunny - you probably found articles like [this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-foundation-help/approve-or-reject-items-or-files-in-a-site-list-or-library-HA101852685.aspx) showing expected solution available. But it is in commercial Sharepoint server...